# How can I automate this Windows GUI with .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, authentication, windows-7, automation

Whenever we get a new release of code from our vendor, we need to perform basic tests to ensure that they did not break functionality we need.

I want to build an automated test for the vendor's infrastructure authentication code.  What it boils down to is automatically submitting this Windows7 [dot1x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X) authentication form:

[image: Windows7 dot1x]

My questions:

- Is there a .NET API to fill this out?  If so, I plan to use [`boo`](http://boo.codehaus.org/), although any .NET language would work.
- Are there other options besides using .NET (such as pre-store auth data in the registry)?

---

**EDIT:**

Nobody explicitly mentioned this resource, but I wound up automating the form with **[AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/)**

Comment: Perhaps related: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/fb94412f-eb6e-42e9-8570-41c4a2cd87c1/ Looks like it's possible on Vista and later by editing the Registry, but not on XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Sikuli helped me a lot in automating Windows GUI tasks like yours. It is easy to do and pretty stable in recognition of what is happening on the screen. http://sikuli.org/

Comment: Thank you, this looks interesting, and it's going in a completely different direction than the assumptions behind my original question.  Our other automation is in [`CPython`](http://www.python.org/), so your suggestion is more appropriate than you may have realized.  I will try it out and see how well it works.